# Lombok @Builder with Inheritance and JPA

Tags: java, jpa, lombok

I have this class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PERSONNE")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@SuperBuilder
@ToString
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = { "personneId" })
public class Personne implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "PERSONNE_ID")
    protected Long personneId;

}
```

and this other one

```
@Entity
    @Table(name = "DISSIDENT")
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "PERSONNE_ID")
    @Data
    @SuperBuilder
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @ToString(callSuper = true)
    @EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
    public class Dissident extends Personne {
    
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    }
```

but when I run a test I got this error:

```
java: constructor Dissident() is already defined in class com.bar.peris.model.Dissident
```

Comment: You don't have to implement Serializable in Dissident

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the order of @NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor. Class by default have a no arg constructor unless a constructor is defined.